# append a jquery variable into a div

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying to append the jquery variable into a div. When i click on the button with id #g noting shows up in my div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#g").click(function() {
        var n = $('#g').val();
        $('#sentence')append('n');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML also please?  There's no way for us to know if you've even se a value on `#g` or if you're trying to get the html, etc.

Comment: Did you mean to write `.append`?

Answer (score 4):

Close

```
$('#sentence').append(n);
```

Remove those quotes around the variable. Also, you're missing a `.` between the selector and `append`

Answer (score 0):

You may have a typo. Try this:

```
$('#sentence').append(n);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove those `''` around `n` (*and you forgot `.` before `append`*)

```
$("#g").click(function() {
    var n = $('#g').val();
    $('#sentence').append(n);
});
```

Comment: Don't forget the `.` before `append`